# MSSQL - JPA - Character encoding for Special characters - appending 'N' nativeQuery

Tags: sql-server, character-encoding, jpa-2.0, spring-4

I'm using Spring 4.3.1 with JPA 2.0 and connected to MSSQL. I'm using JpaRepository's save method to insert and update data. One of the fields has nvarchar which can contain special characters like Latin, Chinese.

Also, I have set below JPA properties in applicationContext-hibernate.xml.

```
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.CharSet">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
```

When I save the data, all the special characters are saved as question marks(??). 
The solution suggested was to append 'N'in front of the update query to keep the special characters inserted. However, I don't see anywhere how to append 'N' in JpaRepository's save method. Any suggestions?

Comment: Might help to use `UTF16`? SQL-Server's `VARCHAR` data type is not `UTF-8` but kind of *extended ASCII* (depending on a `COLLATION`). And be sure to use a `NVARCHAR` column as target. If you store this into a `VARCHAR` column you get question marks too.

Comment: if I change to UTF16, other fields also will get impacted? I will try that. Is there a way in JPA to specify in query that during save, append N in front of the data?

Comment: SQL Server is not capable of `UTF-8` at all (well, last version supports `UTF-8`, but only for `BULK` loads...). Any string you send to SQL-Server will be either taken as *1-byte-encoded-extended-ASCII* (`VARCHAR`) or as `2-byte-enocded unicode / UTF-16 / UCS-2` (`NVARCHAR`). Whatever language or tool you use to communicate with SQL-Server best is to use `2-byte-unicode`

Comment: hmm. thank you.. so does it mean that declaring variable in pojo as below have no effect?                                                                       
 Column(name="[CD Hours of Operation]", columnDefinition = "nvarchar")     do I have to explicitly have to convert the string to 2 byte unicode?

Comment: Sorry, this I don't know... But in any case you should *transmitt* this as *2-byte-unicode* and not as `UTF-8`

Answer (score 0):

Declare field as byte[] array as below.

```
@Column(name="[colName]", columnDefinition = "nvarchar", length=4000)
    private byte[] colName;
```

and while mapping you have to convert byte[] to String using UTF-16 would do the trick as below. 
From DB (mapping):

```
byte[] eCodeData = dbData.getColName();
            if(eCodeData != null){
                uiData.setColName(new String(eCodeData, StandardCharsets.UTF_16));
            }
```

to DB:

```
String eCodeData = uiData.getColName();
        if(eCodeData != null){
            dbData.setColName(eCodeData.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16)); 
        }
```

This is it. This will do the magic.

Answer (score 0):

Actually don't have to define byte[] array for the field but

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "nvarchar(255)")
private String colName;
```

That's enough.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it help others, because I came during research through all this articles in stackoverflow.
My application (Java/Jboss/Hibernate/JPA/M$ SqlServer) was running fine and handling string correctly, coming from UI inputs.
But I also loaded some data via EJB into the database. Here the strings with german Umlaute was corrupted and mapped wrong.
The *.java was correct encoded with UTF-8, all tools showing UTF-8 encoding.

I followed all the advices in the internet/stackoverflow. Using

- encoding
- sendStringParametersAsUnicode=
- extends SQLServerDialect

Nothing really helps.

Finally I found the problem. I was a Gradle problem.
I was calling javac compiler:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.with {
        fork = true
        forkOptions.executable = "${jdk8base}/bin/javac"
    }
}
```

In my environment the source code not interpreted as UTF-8 encoded, so the compiled *.class was interpreted as Latin. EJB was loading Latin into the DB (JPA).

Solution:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.with {
        encoding = 'UTF-8'
        fork = true
        forkOptions.executable = "${jdk8base}/bin/javac"
    }
}
```

So: @Column(columnDefinition = "nvarchar(255)") was enough.