# spring data and hibernate change the string parameters to unicode\ASCII

Tags: hibernate, unicode, spring-data

I have a problem working with sprint data and hibernate. We have a DB that all IDs are char(36), but when I use spring data (for example *findById*) the index is not used since the parameters are sent as unicode whereas the char field is ASCII.

I am working with SQL SERVER and there is a way to set the connection string parameter **sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false** however, this is also not good, since if I have a query which I use to find unicode text, I want the parameters to send as unicode and not ASCII.

Do you know anyway to control (using hibernate or spring data @Query) the behavior for a specific request. I would like to use ASCII by default but when I have some search query to override and use unicode?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't checked yet, although this answer hasn't get any upvote, it might give an inspiration to you. I would give a try.

The key part is setting the column type as byte array and arranging getters/setters with a String constructor having this byte array and the encoding as arguments.

[MSSQL - JPA - Character encoding for Special characters - appending 'N' nativeQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48085062/mssql-jpa-character-encoding-for-special-characters-appending-n-nativequ?rq=1)

> Declare field as byte[] array as below.
>
> ```
> @Column(name="[colName]", columnDefinition = "nvarchar", length=4000)
>     private byte[] colName;
> ```
>
> and while mapping you have to convert byte[] to String using UTF-16
>   would do the trick as below. From DB (mapping):
>
> ```
> byte[] eCodeData = dbData.getColName();
>             if(eCodeData != null){
>                 uiData.setColName(new String(eCodeData, StandardCharsets.UTF_16));
>             }
> ```
>
> to DB:
>
> ```
> String eCodeData = uiData.getColName();
>         if(eCodeData != null){
>             dbData.setColName(eCodeData.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16)); 
>         }
> ```
>
> This is it. This will do the magic.